# Wireshark Lua dissectors: both expand together

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I wrote two simple Wireshark Lua dissectors for chained protocols:

```
local proto1 = Proto("proto1","First Layer")
local page = ProtoField.uint16("proto1.page", "Page", base.HEX)
proto1.fields = {page}

function proto1.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = proto1.name;
    local ptree = tree:add(proto1,buffer(1,5))
    ptree:add(page, buffer(1,2))
    Dissector.get("proto2"):call(buffer(6, 4):tvb(),  pinfo, tree) 
end

local proto2 = Proto("proto2","Second Layer")
local len = ProtoField.uint8("proto2.len", "Payload Length")
proto2.fields = {len}

function proto2.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = proto2.name;
    local ptree = tree:add(proto2,buffer())
    ptree:add(len, buffer(1,2))
end

DissectorTable.get("tcp.port"):add(3456, proto1)
```

The dissectors do work and display protocols in a tree one after another.
Now if I expand one of the protocols (so a protofield is visible) and click on the other packet, then both proto1 and proto2 in a tree are expanded for an unknown reason.
If I now collapse one of the protocols and click on the other packet, then both are collapsed.

Any advise how to avoid it? My protocols are more complex than shown here, so this expansion makes it hard to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug. I could have sworn that was fixed before and then worked correctly.  Please submit a bug on [bugs.wireshark.org](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/).

In the meantime, you can fake it:

```
local proto1 = Proto("proto1","First Layer")

local page    = ProtoField.uint16("proto1.page", "Page", base.HEX)
local proto2  = ProtoField.bytes("proto2","Second Layer")
local len     = ProtoField.uint8("proto2.len", "Payload Length")

proto1.fields = {page, proto2, len}


local function proto2_dissect(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = "proto2"
    local ptree = tree:add(proto2, buffer()):set_text("Second Layer")
    ptree:add(len, buffer(1,2))
end

function proto1.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
    pinfo.cols.protocol = proto1.name;
    local ptree = tree:add(proto1,buffer(1,5))
    ptree:add(page, buffer(1,2))
    proto2_dissect(buffer(6,4):tvb(), pinfo, tree)
end

DissectorTable.get("tcp.port"):add(3456, proto1)
```

Comment: Your example works indeed, thanks.
I do have these protocols in separate files -- is it possible to use your "fake" solution it this case without mixing functions and fields in one file? I tried and got a lot of errors.

Comment: Well, for this work-around to work, you have to register all of the `ProtoField`s to just one `Proto` protocol. Of course you can create the `ProtoField` objects in another Lua file, so long as the other Lua file(s) are loaded before the main one sets the `Proto.fields` - either by using Lua's `require` function (if they're written as Lua modules), or by using `dofile()`. I generally dislike using `dofile()` to load Wireshark plugins, but it's reasonable for loading other Lua files of the same plugin.

Comment: BTW, if you want to just wait a bit, the bug's already in progress and you should be able to download a fixed version tomorrow morning from the [automated builds site][1]. It won't be in an official release until the next 1.12.x release, but that's usually fairly frequent.



  [1]: https://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/